# Having trouble with puts from .yml file

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a YAML file that consists of:

```
---
:feeds:
  -
    title: "Breaking News"
    url: "http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss"
  -
    title: "Education News"
    url: "http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/educationnews.rss"
  -
    title: "Space Station News"
    url: "http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/shuttle_station.rss"
```

And my ruby file consists of:

```
require 'yaml'
config = YAML.load_file('settings.yml')
feeds = config[:feeds]


feeds.each do |entry|
  puts "Title: #{entry[:title]}"
end
```

What I'm expecting to see is "Title: Breaking News", for example. However the output is simply putting "Title: ". I believe I have an error with the hash, but have tried many things and am just guessing at this point. I've searched on here for similar issues, but couldn't find anything related. Probably because this is a simple misunderstanding on my part.

Answer (score 2):

The keys to the inner hashes are strings, not symbols. You’re trying to find `entry[:title]`, which doesn’t exist – you should be using `entry['title']`:

```
feeds.each do |entry|
  puts "Title: #{entry['title']}"
end
```

Alternatively you could use symbols in your yaml (you are already doing this for the `:feeds` key):

```
---
:feeds:
  -
    :title: "Breaking News"
    :url: "http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss"
  -
    :title: "Education News"
    :url: "http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/educationnews.rss"
  -
    :title: "Space Station News"
    :url: "http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/shuttle_station.rss"
```